# HSP to C++: Language conversion of a large codebase

Tags: c++, converters

I have large codebase written in [HSP](http://lhsp.s206.xrea.com/index.en.html)([wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Soup_Processor) - think "BASIC", but japanese).

By "large" I mean it has 151352 lines of code, 60 source files with total code size of 4.5 megabytes. Also, it has plenty of spaghetti code, no comments and badly needs refactoring. The good thing is that it has a lot of text messages, so not all of those lines represent actual program logic.

I'd like to convert this codebase to C++, while retaining my sanity. "I'd like" means that I'm not **required** to do it, but I'd strongly prefer to find a method to do it.

What's a good way to do it? Obviously, I can't just rewrite it all in C++ (Well, I *could* do it in theory, but it would take up to 2 years, and I would introduce many bugs in process), so (I think) a reasonable decision would be to implement code recompiler/preprocessor that would allow me to convert source code into messy C++ (HSP is much simpler than C++, so it should be possible) and then start refactoring/documenting the result.

Unfortunately, i'm not entirely sure how to approach building the recompiler efficiently. While I know there are Lex/Yacc/Bison/Boost::spirit, I haven't used them personally.

So can you recommend a good way perform such conversion?
Any free tool ("free" as in "free beer") that is available on windows platform is allowed, as long as it doesn't affect license of original source code.

Comment: why do you need to rewrite, if you can't afford the time to do it? If its spaghetti now, the conversion will give you more spaghetti.

Comment: What would be the point of auto-converting spaghetti code into another language?  The resulting code could only be worse.  Plus it won't be anything close to idiomatic C++, so refactoring == rewriting in that case.

Comment: Can you create a virtual machine where an environment for HSP would be preserved and leave there?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: "What would be the point of auto-converting spaghetti code into another language?" The point that I'm **much** more skilled in C++ than in HSP and it would be easier to add certain missing features in language I'm familiar with. HSP also has certain severe limitations (like "all variables are global") that would prevent proper cleanup.

Comment: @MitchWheat: See 2nd paragraph. I'm not required to do it, but I'm looking for a good way to approach the problem.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: HSP has compiler that produces native windows executable. Compiler is available, and I could attempt to refactor original code instead. However, right now I'm investigating other possibilities.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: "What would be the point" Another thing is that if I want to do a rewrite, I can't rewrite it all at once, so I need to keep portions original code working AND make them interact with new C++ code. This way I'll be able to test new portions of code (to see if I broke something or not), while keeeping app functional. So I need cross-language bridge. One way to do it is to implement recompiler - make a C++ mess out of original code and make new hand-written code interact with original code that has been automatically converted. As far as I can tell, this approach makes sense.

Comment: Well, what you want to do is to create a compiler that compiles an obscure language to C++ code. Then, you'll need to find out the lex/yacc grammar matching your original language to generate your Abstract Syntax Tree, and then you can work out some optimization (like changing the scope of globals etc..) and finally output C++ code. That's for the theory.

Comment: In practice, it'll take you minimum a year to get a full featured compiler working to get good results on that kind of project (maybe a bit less if you use a functional programing language). You'll get a code that is neither understandable or reusable, and you'll end up either writing HSP code (because you'll know perfectly the language) or rewriting the whole in C++. Believe my experience, I had to do that kind of work before, and it took me one year to get something correct (but we had to build a C++ template engine, and I wrote comments preservation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to original owner of the codebase, HSP starting with version 3 includes HSP to C code converter. Information is not verified due to lack of time, but this [blog article](http://www.onionsoft.net/wp/archives/433) documents the tool called hspcnv which is supposed to convert HSP code into C code. The article is in japanese.

Answer (score 1):

Yacc it's targeted to efficiently handle more complex tasks, and it's complex to learn, I think it's overkill.

Spirit should be a better choice, if you already know go with it, personally I would use Prolog for this task.

Prolog has builtin syntax analysis, so called DCG. For a language simple as Basic, I'm pretty sure there are no practical problems in the grammar, and modern Prologs (I think to SWI-Prolog, effectively) can handle complex characters encoding in the source very well.

Also, in Prolog you could try to apply some naivety to unroll the spaghetti code. Doing in general it's a complex task, but could be easy if you have just a small number of patterns, repeated many times.

Pattern matching it's key in such problems...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to go this way and forget about the advices in the comment, you should probably have a good look at the openhsp compiler, and mostly the codegen file :

- http://dev.onionsoft.net/trac/browser/trunk/hspcmp/codegen.cpp

and also have the tokens under your eyes :

- http://dev.onionsoft.net/trac/browser/trunk/hspcmp/token.h
- http://dev.onionsoft.net/trac/browser/trunk/hspcmp/token.cpp

it seems that HSP is not that complicated, and you can skip the AST step. Though, you could get good optimizations out of that. Don't forget also to prepare a C++ lib to embed your generated code in, so you can manage HSP oddities (like globals, and dynamic typing).

if you can hack something out of that, you'll also have to remove most of what this compiler does (create executable, linkage and stuff). Don't forget, it's a really long and hard task that may not be faster or easier than a full rewrite. But if you're ready, you'll find it out the hard way :)